# Regular value of a function $f_\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, let $f_\lambda:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ be the function given by $f_\lambda(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2-z^2, x + y + \lambda z)$.

Now I should find every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(1,0)$ is a regular value of $f_\lambda$. Calculating the jacobian matrix for $(x,y,z)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R^3}$:
$$J_{f_\lambda} = \begin{pmatrix} 2x & 2y & -2z \\ 1 & 1 & \lambda \end{pmatrix} $$

Now I should be able to show that if $(x,y,z) \in N_{(1,0)}(f)$, then $J_{f_\lambda}(x,y,z)$ has rank $2$ but I don't know how to use it in an helpful manner. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not start by finding where the jacobian has rank $1$?

Comment: The only points that satisfy that condition are $(x,x,-\lambda x)$; $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and it can be verified that no points of this form are in $N_{(1,0)}(f)$. Is that so?

Comment: Not $-\lambda x$, though.